# IllegalStateException in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I am calling an `AsyncTask` from my activity to download a string from the web. When the string has been downloaded, I want to pass the string into my activity so I can parse it and then populate the `ListView`.

I created a method in my activity to be called in `onPostExecute()` and this is what the code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {   
        IndexPicker index = new IndexPicker();
        index.onAsyncFinish(res);
    }
```

This is my `onASyncFinish()` method:

```
public void onAsyncFinish(String json) {
        ArrayList<Index> arrayList = parseJSON(json);
        populateListView(arrayList);
    }
}
```

In the `populateListView` method is where the IllegalStateException, when the constructor for the ArrayAdapter is called.

```
public IndexItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Index> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data); // This line.
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
```

This is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.test.exampleapp.index.IndexItemAdapter.<init>(IndexItemAdapter.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.test.exampleapp.activity.IndexPicker.populateListView(IndexPicker.java:39)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.test.exampleapp.activity.IndexPicker.onAsyncFinish(IndexPicker.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.test.exampleapp.async.DownloadIndexJSON.onPostExecute(DownloadIndexJSON.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.test.exampleapp.async.DownloadIndexJSON.onPostExecute(DownloadIndexJSON.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After researching, apparently the problem is the way I am calling the onASyncFinish method, using `IndexPicker index = new IndexPicker();`. I believe this is correct as when I tried doing the networking on the main thread as a test, the listview would populate correctly.

So my question is, what would be the best way for me to fix this so I can pass the result of my ASyncTask to the activity and then populate my list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `IndexPicker` is your `Activity`, in which case you're doing a really bad thing instantiating it(as it will not have a valid `Context`(exactly what the exception is telling you)). Activities shouldn't be instantiated manually, they are created and handled by the Android system.

Instead, to do what you want, you should pass a reference to the `Activity` from where you start that `AsyncTask`(in the `AsyncTask`'s constructor) and use that reference to call `onAsyncFinish` in the `onPostExecute` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here two possible solution:

One :: Send you Listview Reference to the ASyncTask  and bind data to listview when ASyncTask  is finish.

Two:: you want to bind data in listview  in activity then first check the ASyncTask  is finish is work then bind data. To take data from ASyncTask , you need create a method in ASyncTask  class call it when it finish , this method return type is return your data.

But I think the second method is not good because you need run one thread to continue check the ASyncTask  is finish.

Thanks